# How can I transfer a domain from get.blog to another registrar?

Tags: blog, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I've registered a .blog domain on http://get.blog, now I want to transfer it to another registrar, how can I do that? I can't find any option on the control panel to generate the Authorization Code or any article with more information regarding this.

Comment: Contact the domain register company on anyway. You know about authorization code it means you have experience or read something about domain transfer. Can't help you bro, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the get.blog site:

> Can I transfer my domain?
>
> You can transfer your domain from get.blog to any other domain seller that supports it. However, new domains cannot be transferred for 60 days after they are registered. This “lock” period is standard for all domains. You can still start using your domain during this time, for example by setting custom name servers. Contact us at help@get.blog for help with transferring your domain.

https://get.blog/learn-more